# Ищу список бесплатных шрифтов TTF

Tags: шрифты, ttf

Привет всем! Возникла такая проблема - разрабатываю один веб-проект, там используется пару десятков различных шрифтов TTF. Заказчик очень переживает, что не которые шрифты не являются бесплатными и за них нужно платить лицензионные отчисления. Сайт будет кроссбраузерным, то есть должен будет работать в любом браузере и любой ОС. Вопрос такой - может кто встречал в сети Интернет список бесплатных шрифтов TTF для операционных систем Windows, Linux и MacOS? Буду очень благодарен тому, кто поможет раздобыть такой список, так как поиск по Гуглу не дал особых результатов - сразу предлагает скачать бесплатный шрифт.

Comment: Уточню немного вопрос - интересуют только те шрифты TTF, которые используются по-умолчанию данными операционными системами!

Comment: Если эти шрифты и так есть в ОС по умолчанию, зачем их встраивать?

Comment: Смотрите, допустим пользователь выбирает шрифт **"Helvetica"**, который есть в MacOS, а сам работает под ОС Windows XP - у него возникнут проблемы при открытии сохраненного файла сайтом. Поэтому я и ищу список бесплатных TTF шрифтов, которые используются в ОС Windows, Linux и MacOS. Чтобы не достающие шрифты можно было встроить в генерируемый файл и он без проблем работал на перечисленных ОС.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, дык, [Liberation](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_(шрифты)) же!

Comment: Спасибо, за ссылку, сейчас почитаю. Почитал, но этой информации не достаточно, но все равно спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Я вот нашел список шрифтов, которые используются в [ОС Windows](http://www.fortress-design.com/spisok-standartnyh-shriftov-windows/), но как узнать какие из них платные, а какие можно использовать бесплатно?

Вот тут нашел список шрифтов, которые используются в [MacOS](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1642?viewlocale=ru_RU&locale=ru_RU). Вопрос тот же!

С Линуксом тяжелее, сейчас попробую поискать какие шрифты по-умолчанию используются в Ubuntu.